# Get current post's child page?

Tags: posts, pages, single, wp-list-pages, child-pages

Is it possible to find out what page a post is contained in?

Im in my single.php template and im listing child pages in a sidebar using wp_list_pages, I want the page (not category) that the post is visible in to be highlighted, or add current_page_item to it, is this possible? It works everywhere else at the moment except for the single.php template.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ancestors = array();
$ancestors = get_ancestors($post->ID,'page');
$parent = (!empty($ancestors)) ? array_pop($ancestors) : $post->ID;
```

`$parent` should be the topmost page parent.

However, if you are using a WordPress generated menu there is a pretty good chance that there is already a item identified by a CSS class as the parent. Take a good look at the generated markup.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu#Menu_Item_CSS_Classes

Note: using `wp_list_pages`, for nested pages, `current_page_parent` applies to the immediate parent only but `current_page_ancestor` is applied to all of the parent pages. That is the class you want (I think). Just adjust your CSS.

Comment: That throws back a different page ID than i require! and yes i am using a wp generates menu

Comment: Then your description is not adequate to identify the problem. What post/page ID do you require?

Comment: Im using wp_list_pages to list child pages in a sidebar. So for example, if im in 'About', it lists the child pages of 'About'. If i click one of them, for example 'About Child' it takes me to that page and it spits out the class current_page_item in the sidebar for the page named 'About Child'. If i then click onto a post inside 'About Child', which takes me into my single.php template, i loose the current_page_item in the sidebar, im trying to retain it

Comment: @user34466 : see the edit

Comment: thanks i really appreciate your help, just tested, i noticed what its doing now, its giving me the id of the current post, but not the child page i need still

Comment: Your title is "Get current post's parent page?" but you want the _child page_? Anyway, I still see a `current_page_item` class for the page.

Comment: better? regardless, your code dosent work. thanks anyway

Comment: Of course it doesn't work. What you are now asking for is exactly opposite of what you started out asking for.